# add action wp_head not working

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, actions, wp-head, options

I am trying to add some code to the head (namely a block of tracking script) via a plugin I am making.

The plugin has an interface where the user enters some details which are then added to the options table. This is all working perfectly fine so far. But then I want to write a conditional statement if there is an open then add to head. Basically I have this all in the main plugin file and it looks like this;

```
if(get_option( 'MyOptionName' )){
    function testingone(){ ?>
        <script>var Script = GoesHere; </script>
    <?php ;}
    add_action('wp_head','testingone');
}
```

I have tried placing this inside the actual block that pulls the data and then adds to options, but that didn't work, then I decided to do it this way, where it looks to see if there is an option in the table but this also doesnt inject anything to the head. Some places I have seen people put the add_action above the function, but in the codex it shows an example of it below. but either way I have tried and failed.

Can anyone see where this is going wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried `echo`ing or `print_r` the value to see what it's returning? Perhaps it's as simple as a typo in your option name compared to the `wp_options` entry

Comment: Change `if(get_option( 'MyOptionName' )){` to `if ( true ) {`. If the code is added then you know that `get_option( 'MyOptionName' )` is coming up as `false`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pull the `add_action()` outside of the function, and put the conditional inside the callback. Also, if you're printing a script directly, use `wp_print_scripts` instead of `wp_head`. You also have a syntax error.

```
function testingone(){ 
    if( get_option( 'MyOptionName' ) ) {
        ?>
        <script>var Script = GoesHere; </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts','testingone' );
```

Comment: This worked perfectly many thanks. the above method also worked, but if wp_print_scripts is a better practice I will use that.

Answer (score 3):

Try turning your code around:

```
function testingone() {
    if( FALSE !== get_option( 'MyOptionName' ) ) {
        echo( 'ok, this is in the head!' );
    } 
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'testingone' );
```

As well, check in your theme's files (most likely `header.php`) to make sure that the `wp_head()` function is being called, and make sure that the `MyOptionName` option is set for the site.

**Edited to add** -- You should also use `wp_enqueue_script()` to add Javascript to your site, rather than just dumping them into the `<head>`.

#### References

- [`wp_head` (action)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head)
- [`wp_head()` (function)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head)
- [`get_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)
- [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: Didn't quite work this way for me, but I did try wp_print_scripts as suggested by Chip Bennett and that worked. But thanks for the help and advice anyway. cheers

Answer (score 3):

see below code.Add `IF` statement inside the function.

```
function testingone(){ 
    if(get_option( 'MyOptionName' )){
    ?>
    <script>var Script = GoesHere; </script>
    <?php } 
      }
add_action('wp_head','testingone');
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, although I was sure I tried this method before, obviously not :) Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function plugin_script() {
       wp_enqueue_script( 'Jquery-min', WP_PLUGIN_URL. '/Test Plugin/jquery-min.js', false, '1.11.0' );<br/>
       wp_enqueue_style('pluginstyle', WP_PLUGIN_URL. '/Test Plugin/pluginstyle.css',false,'1.0',"all");<br/>
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'plugin_script' );
```

The "wp_head" action hook is triggered within the "head" section.

wp_enqueue_script() is used for executing scripts and wp_enqueue_style is for stylesheet from Plugin.
"WP_PLUGIN_URL." will get data from plugin folder of themes.
"Test plugin" is your plugin Name
"pluginstyle.css" plugin stylesheet.
"jquery-min.js" plugin script.

Comment: Please explain how it answers, just dumping code is not a good answer

Comment: it is not dumped type of code i have already used in my plugin.what is your doubt you ask me i will clarify in that code.

Comment: did you try using that code @ bravokey

Comment: I didn't try it, I was suggesting you to write some explanation in addition to the code posted as how it answers the original question.

Comment: Thanks for your sugeestion actually i am new to this @ bravokeyl

Comment: Please see [answer]